pyspark .display() works but .collect(), .distinct() and show() don't
I'm working with a pyspark dataframe in Azure Databricks and I'm trying to count how many unique (distinct) values a particular column has.

Cluster: 14.3 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.5.0, Scala 2.12)
pandas                   1.5.3
pyspark                  3.3.0

I can .display() and .count() the df without problems, but when I try any of these three commands
df.select("PB_countProducts").distinct().count()
df.collect()
df.show()

I get this error:
SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 6 in stage 57.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 6.3 in stage 57.0 (TID 421) (10.43.64.12 executor 0): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to create session
    at com.databricks.spark.api.python.IsolatedPythonWorkerFactory.createRawIsolatedWorker(IsolatedPythonWorkerFactory.scala:233)
    at com.databricks.spark.api.python.IsolatedPythonWorkerFactory.create(IsolatedPythonWorkerFactory.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createIsolatedPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:325)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BasePythonUDFRunner.compute(PythonUDFRunner.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvalPythonEvaluatorFactory$EvalPythonPartitionEvaluator.eval(EvalPythonEvaluatorFactory.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvalPythonExec.$anonfun$doExecute$2(EvalPythonExec.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvalPythonExec.$anonfun$doExecute$2$adapted(EvalPythonExec.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndexInternal$2(RDD.scala:920)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndexInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:920)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$computeOrReadCheckpoint$1(RDD.scala:409)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$computeOrReadCheckpoint$1(RDD.scala:409)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$computeOrReadCheckpoint$1(RDD.scala:409)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ShuffleMapTask.scala:88)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ShuffleMapTask.scala:87)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$5(Task.scala:151)
    at com.databricks.unity.UCSEphemeralState$Handle.runWith(UCSEphemeralState.scala:45)
    at com.databricks.unity.HandleImpl.runWith(UCSHandle.scala:103)
    at com.databricks.unity.HandleImpl.$anonfun$runWithAndClose$1(UCSHandle.scala:108)
    at scala.util.Using$.resource(Using.scala:269)
    at com.databricks.unity.HandleImpl.runWithAndClose(UCSHandle.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:145)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$9(Executor.scala:958)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:961)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:853)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: RawInitSandboxError: [IndexOutOfBoundsException] readerIndex(8) + length(2067) exceeds writerIndex(2048): PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 8, widx: 2048, cap: 2048)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkThreadUtils$.awaitResult(SparkThreadUtils.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:462)
    at com.databricks.spark.api.python.IsolatedPythonWorkerFactory.createRawIsolatedWorker(IsolatedPythonWorkerFactory.scala:230)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: RawInitSandboxError: [IndexOutOfBoundsException] readerIndex(8) + length(2067) exceeds writerIndex(2048): PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 8, widx: 2048, cap: 2048)
    at daemon.safespark.client.SandboxApiClient.rawInitSandbox(SandboxApiClient.scala:272)
    at com.databricks.spark.safespark.ApiAdapter.rawInitSandbox(ApiAdapter.scala:123)
    at com.databricks.spark.safespark.udf.DispatcherImpl.$anonfun$createRawConnection$3(DispatcherImpl.scala:142)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$recordOperation$1(UsageLogging.scala:573)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.executeThunkAndCaptureResultTags$1(UsageLogging.scala:669)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$recordOperationWithResultTags$4(UsageLogging.scala:687)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:426)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.logging.AttributionContext$.withValue(AttributionContext.scala:216)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:424)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:418)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.withAttributionContext(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:27)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:472)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:455)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.withAttributionTags(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:27)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperationWithResultTags(UsageLogging.scala:664)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperationWithResultTags$(UsageLogging.scala:582)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.recordOperationWithResultTags(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:27)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperation(UsageLogging.scala:573)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperation$(UsageLogging.scala:542)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:27)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.recordOperation0(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:68)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:150)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogger.recordOperation(UsageLogger.scala:68)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogger.recordOperation$(UsageLogger.scala:55)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:109)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging.recordOperation(UsageLogger.scala:429)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging.recordOperation$(UsageLogger.scala:408)
    at com.databricks.spark.safespark.udf.DispatcherImpl.recordOperation(DispatcherImpl.scala:67)
    at com.databricks.spark.safespark.udf.DispatcherImpl.recordDispatcherOperation(DispatcherImpl.scala:443)
    at com.databricks.spark.safespark.udf.DispatcherImpl.$anonfun$createRawConnection$2(DispatcherImpl.scala:130)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$.$anonfun$apply$1(Future.scala:659)
    at scala.util.Success.$anonfun$map$1(Try.scala:255)
    at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:213)
    at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$map$1(Future.scala:292)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:33)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:33)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$$anon$1.execute(ThreadUtils.scala:105)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$$anon$4.execute(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:138)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:72)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$KeptPromise$Kept.onComplete(Promise.scala:372)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$KeptPromise$Kept.onComplete$(Promise.scala:371)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$KeptPromise$Successful.onComplete(Promise.scala:379)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.transform(Promise.scala:33)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.transform$(Promise.scala:31)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$KeptPromise$Successful.transform(Promise.scala:379)
    at scala.concurrent.Future.map(Future.scala:292)
    at scala.concurrent.Future.map$(Future.scala:292)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$KeptPromise$Successful.map(Promise.scala:379)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$.apply(Future.scala:659)
    at com.databricks.spark.safespark.udf.DispatcherImpl.createRawConnection(DispatcherImpl.scala:169)
    at com.databricks.spark.safespark.Dispatcher.createRawConnection(Dispatcher.scala:156)
    at com.databricks.spark.api.python.IsolatedPythonWorkerFactory.createRawIsolatedWorker(IsolatedPythonWorkerFactory.scala:228)
    ... 54 more

Driver stacktrace:

JVM stacktrace:
org.apache.spark.SparkException
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:3908)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:3830)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:3817)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:3817)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1695)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1680)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1680)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:4154)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:4066)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:4054)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:54)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to create session

I tried to come up with a df_fake to enable you to reproduce the problem, with the same columns and values, but when I create it from data and scheme, all these functions work.
Here's what I did to create the df_fake:
# Create a Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("CreateDeltaTable").getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.enableVectorizedReader","false")

data = [("3bf293f7-f093-4943-9e1f-1e9eb313c9d6", 1),
        ("f8342388-3b17-4043-8a5a-73c56335181f", 1),
        ("1a6d1a34-4291-4e24-b00e-45600c04bc55", 2)]

columns = ["RequestId", "PB_countProducts"]
df_fake = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
df_fake = df_fake.withColumn("PB_countProducts", F.col("PB_countProducts").cast("integer"))
df_fake.display()

when I display my problematic df (called df) and my fake df (df_fake), they look alike:
df.display()
df_fake.display()


When I print dtypes, they look alike:
print(df.dtypes)
print(df_fake.dtypes)

[('RequestId', 'string'), ('PB_countProducts', 'int')]
[('RequestId', 'string'), ('PB_countProducts', 'int')]
When I print their scheme, they look alike:
print(df.printSchema())
print(df_fake.printSchema())

root
|-- RequestId: string (nullable = true)
|-- PB_countProducts: integer (nullable = true)
None
root
|-- RequestId: string (nullable = true)
|-- PB_countProducts: integer (nullable = true)
None
but when I try .collect() (or any of the mentioned functions), I get errors only for df, while df_fake works fine:
print(df_fake.collect())

[Row(RequestId='3bf293f7-f093-4943-9e1f-1e9eb313c9d6', PB_countProducts=1), Row(RequestId='f8342388-3b17-4043-8a5a-73c56335181f', PB_countProducts=1), Row(RequestId='1a6d1a34-4291-4e24-b00e-45600c04bc55', PB_countProducts=2)]

print(df.collect()) will generate the error above.

Any idea on what I can do? ChatGPT wasn't very helpful...neither was databrick's assistant.
Update: After trying a lot of stuff, the problem was solved. Here a couple of things that may or may not have solved it:

I was installing several packages at the beginning of the code and some of them could be interfering with others (package versioning have been hard to manage).
One of the columns was filled with dictionaries and I manage to identify that they were the only column where I coudn't .distinct.count(). So dropping it helped.


@mazaneicha really? do you have a hypothesis of what might be causing it?

I solved it. I've included an Update if you're interested in knowing about it.

Thanks for the update. Glad it got resolved.
